# Youtube API viewcount not working

Tags: youtube-api

I am accessing a profile/channel info form the youtube api and getting back number that seem off. I am using: http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/?v=2.

The viewCount field hasn't changed. This is supposed to be the number of views out there for the user's channel. It hasn't updated since the 16th of september, and this is the same for several high traffic accounts. I read a lot online about this happening with the youtube site itself, but what I read makes it seem like the issue was resolved. I can't find the stat on youtube itself to compare so I don't know if this is the case.

Does anyone know if youtube isn't tracking this anymore? Or is it just not being updated in the api?

Answer (score 1):

The last I heard was that this specific attribute will no longer be updated due to a policy decision. Once we're sure that that's the final word, we'll update the documentation to reflect that.

Apologies for any inconvenience this change might have caused.

Answer (score 0):

This is most likely just due to the caching infrastructure at YouTube.  I should be updated shortly.

If you believe it is a bug please file a report at [https://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/entry?template=YouTube%20(Defect%20Report)](https://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/entry?template=YouTube%20%28Defect%20Report%29)

Comment: It's deliberate; see my response.